# $S_7$ is isomorphic to subgroup of all those elements of of $S_8$ that sends $8$ to $8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I have to show that $S_7$ is isomorphic to the subgroup of all those elements of $S_8$ that sends $8$ to $8$.

**My attempt**: let $H$ be subgroup of $S_8$ such that all elements of $H$ sends $8$ to $8$ that is, all elements of $H$ fix the symbol $8$. I had defined map $f$ from  $H$ to $S_7$ such that if $\alpha\in H$ then $f(\alpha)= \beta$ where $\beta= \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 & \cdots & 7\\ \alpha(1) & \alpha(2) & \cdots & \alpha(7)\end{smallmatrix}\right)$

I had already proved that $f$ is bijective. **But I am not able to show $f$ is homomorphism** (operation preserving) map. i.e. **how to show** $f(\alpha_1\alpha_2)= f(\alpha_1)f(\alpha_2)$

Please help.

Comment: $f(\alpha_1\alpha_2)(s)$ is what when $s \neq 8$? What is it when $s = 8$? Compare to what $(f(\alpha_1)f(\alpha_2)(s)$ should be.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1458979/isomorphism-of-stabilizer-over-s-n-to-s-n-1), why it is an isomorphism in general.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг sir how to compare? Please elaborate. (Sir first we have to compute $\alpha_1\alpha_2$ then we have to compute $f(\alpha_1\alpha_2)$ and then after this we have to check how this permutation map the symbol $s$)

Comment: First : does the given link by Dietrich help you? Read the second paragraph of the body of the question  he linked for a worded description of the isomorphism.

Comment: Ok, I will answer this question. But first : I want you to be comfortable with this definition : $S_n$ is the group of all bijections from $\{1,2,...,n\}$ to itself. The group operation is composition. The problem is, when you write it in cycle notation, you can get confused as to the essential nature of the operation. Also, I need to have dinner (19:00 is just about right) so I will get back to you after that! LBNL, you can call me ACTOH.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг sir, yes I am comfortable with it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde sir, now I get the answer in the link that you had mentioned ( thank you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\l}[1]{\{1,2,\ldots,#1\}}$

First, I make the map explicit.

Let $\phi \in S_8$ be a map sending $8$ to $8$. We define $$f(\phi) : \l{7} \to \l{7} \quad ; \quad (f(\phi))(x) = \phi(x)$$

Now we have to prove that $f(\phi)\circ f(\psi) = f (\phi \circ \psi)$ for every $\phi,\psi \in S_8$ which send $8$ to $8$.

To do this, simply check what each side is, evaluated at some $x \in \l{7}$.

By definition, we have \begin{align}
f(\phi \circ \psi)(x)  = &\phi \circ \psi(x) &\text{definition of $f$} \\ =& \phi(\psi(x)) &\text{definition of composition} \\ = &\phi((f(\psi))(x)) &\text{definition of $f$, inner bracket} \\ 
= &\big(f(\phi)\big) \big((f(\psi))(x)\big) &\text{see *  below} 
\\ =& [f(\phi) \circ f(\psi)](x) &\text{definition of composition} 
\end{align}

for all $x$, hence $f(\phi \circ \psi) = f(\phi) \circ f(\psi)$. We get the homomorphism property.

---

(*) The way this is is being applied is that $\phi(y) = (f(\phi)) (y)$ for any $ y$ by definition of $f$. Now simply put $y = (f(\psi))(x)$ to get that statement.

Comment: Sir, thanks for tha answer. you didn't consider the image of symbol $8$ under $f(\phi)$.Is because $f(\phi)$ is permutation on seven symbols?

Comment: Exactly : $f(\phi)$ is an element of $S_7$, so it is not defined at $8$. This is because we want $f$ to map to $S_7$ as $f$ is the isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for the up vote and accept! If you think my answers are nice, you can call me to your questions via this link and I will attend to them?

Comment: Ok sure sir. Thank you once again

Answer (score 2):

In general, let $X$ be a set and $Y \subseteq X$. For a given bijection $u$ on $X \setminus Y$, any bijection $\alpha$ on $Y$ can be extended to a bijection $f_u(\alpha)$ on $X$ by:

\begin{alignat}{1}
&f_u(\alpha)_{|Y}:=\alpha \\
&f_u(\alpha)_{|X \setminus Y}:=u \\
\tag 1
\end{alignat}

Note that $f_u(\alpha)=f_u(\beta) \Rightarrow f_u(\alpha)_{|Y}=f_u(\beta)_{|Y} \Rightarrow \alpha=\beta$, so that $f_u$ is injective for all $u \in \operatorname{Sym}(X \setminus Y)$. Moreover,

$$f_u(\alpha\beta)=f_u(\alpha)f_u(\beta) \iff u=\iota_{X \setminus Y} \tag 2$$

($\iota_A$ is the identical map on the set $A$: $\iota_A(a)=a$ for every $a \in A$.) Therefore, if we take $u=\iota_{X \setminus Y}$, we have $f_u : {\rm{Sym}}(Y) \hookrightarrow {\rm{Sym}}(X)$. Now, take $Y:=\{1,\dots,7\}\subseteq X:=\{1,\dots,8\}$, and you're done.

Comment: Sir what is $u=\iota_{X \setminus Y} \tag 2$

Comment: Just edited, hope it's clear now.